# Discrete Math - RSA Encryption problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am doing practice problems for my upcoming final exam, and am having trouble with this RSA encryption problem. If any one could check to see if i did these correctly, it would be greatly appreciated.

For (a) I got Z* = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},

(b) i got 3*3 = 1(mod 8) = 3^(-1) = 3

(c) this one i am not sure how to do

(d) M = N^(d) mod 15, i got d = 3, so M = 4^(3) mod 15 = 4

[image]

Comment: Good work so far! Note that $\Bbb Z^* = \{1,3,5,7\}$—do you see why $2,4,6$ shouldn't be included? As for (c), do you know Euler's theorem involving $\phi(15)$?

Comment: 2-6 should be omitted because they are even right?

Comment: Yes: more specifically, they should be omitted because they are not relatively prime to the modulus $8$.

Comment: thank you for the help @GregMartin